# index in getLeaf is not the same as that in getText

Tags: quill

i write a simple html text inside editor,and set editor a little narrow to make the text line did wrap

```
<p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
```

but the index in getLeaf(index) looks is different with getText(index,length)

```
quill.getText()="Some initial bold text\n"
quill.getText(14,4)="old " //equals quill.getText().substr(14,4)
quill.getLeaf(14)[0].text="bold"  //yes,it is right
quill.getLeaf(13)[0].text="Some initial " // WHY? 
quill.getBounds(14)={bottom: 47.79999923706055, height: 14.39999771118164, left: 24, right: 24, top: 33.400001525878906, width: 0}
quill.getBounds(13)={ bottom: 29.400001525878906, height: 14.400001525878906, left: 84, right: 84, top: 15, width: 0 }
```

does `quill.getLeaf(13)` should be the same as `quill.getLeaf(14)`?
PS:the index of`quill.getBounds(index)` looks is same as `quill.getLeaf(index)`

check the codepen please
https://codepen.io/minzojian/pen/ROLyeZ

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

- `getText` returns text to the *right* of `index`
- `getLeaf` returns the blot to the *left* of `index`

For example, given this document:

```
[
  {
    "insert": "a"
  },
  {
    "insert": "b",
    "attributes": { "bold": true }
  },
  {
    "insert: "c",
    "attributes": { "italic": true }
  }
]
```

Then you get the following results:

```
quill.getLeaf(0) // a (the 0-index is a slightly special case)
quill.getText(0) // "abc"

quill.getLeaf(1) // a
quill.getText(1) // "bc"

quill.getLeaf(2) // b
quill.getText(2) // "c"

quill.getLeaf(3) // c
quill.getText(3) // ""
```

Comment: thanks for your help. i will check it out base your explain